# How do you make a form identifier equal to the value of a string variable in C#?

Tags: c#

So , I have a function called CreateWindow(string id,int width,int height,string title);

as you might have guessed, this function creates a window whenever called and adds the parameters. I plan to do it like this:

```
public static void CreateWindow(string id,int width,int height,string title) {
Form (value of id) = new Form();
(value of id).Text = title;
(value of id).Size = new Size(width,height);
Main(Form (value of id));
}
```

But, I need to make the identifier of the form equal to the variable 'id' or I won't be able to get anything done, I can't just replace `(value of id)`with , for instance `form1`because if the user wants to change another property of the window he should be able to simply do, for instance: `(value of id).BackColor = Color.Green;`

Comment: These are local variables. No matter how they are named, nobody else will be able to access them. Maybe what you need is a `static Dictionary<string, Form>`?

Comment: Agree with the above comment.  It feels like you're getting the ideas of variables and references confused.

Comment: Why not save the id as a property of the form (let's say Name)?

Comment: You are trying to write generic code.  So use generics:  static void CreateWindow<T>(...) where T : Form.  If it absolutely has to be a string then look at Activator.CreateInstance().

Answer (score 2):

I've added a complete program for you to try below, without any error handling to keep it short.  Just create a new windows application and paste the code in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CreateFormWindowSO
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var windowId = "Some window";
            CreateWindow(windowId, 320, 240, "My Window");

            // Put a breakpoint on the line below and step over it with the debugger.
            // You'll see it returns the correct form object that was created above.
            var someWindow = GetWindow(windowId);

            // Do something with 'someWindow'.
        }

        static Form GetWindow(string id)
        {
            return windows[id];
        }

        static void CreateWindow(string id, int width, int height, string title)
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            form.Text = title;
            form.Size = new Size(width, height);

            windows.Add(id, form);
        }

        static Dictionary<string, Form> windows = new Dictionary<string, Form>();
    }
}
```

The idea behind the dictionary is you're now able to *associate* a `Form` with a particular 'key' (i.e. `id` in this case).  That enables you to look up a particular window by supplying `GetWindow()` with a key that you presumably keep track of elsewhere.  You can now create windows separately, and fetch them at any point later on whenever you need them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that dynamic variable naming is possible. You could have a static dictionary of forms such as `public static Dictionary<string, Form> forms;` and add your new forms to the collection using the id for the index.

```
public static Dictionary<string, Form> forms = new Dictionary<string, Form>();

public static Form CreateWindow(string id, int width, int height, string title)
{
    if (!forms.ContainsKey(id))
        forms.Add(id, new Form());
    forms[id].Text = title;
    forms[id].Width = width;
    forms[id].Height = height;
    return forms[id];
}
```

Comment: Ok, everybody suggests using a dictionary. Can anyone please give me the full code? I've never used a dictionary before (in C#) so could you please explain it?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to both return the form and add it to the colleciton. If you decide to change from a Dictionary<string, Form> to another collection type, would you really want to modify the method responsible for creating the Form object? This looks like a prime candidate for a method that might get extracted into a factory class later on. A method called "CreateWindow" should create the form and return a reference to it. Leave it up to the calling code to decide how to name and store the form.

Comment: Just to show how to create, add to and reference from a dictionary. But yes, I agree.

Comment: Harris your program gives me the error: "No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Missed the index param. Edited now.